# Grails Upgrade 2.4.4 to 2.5.2 Error running unit tests: null

Tags: grails, upgrade

I'm upgrading a Grails app from 2.4.4 to 2.5.2 and when I try and run `test-app`, I'm getting the following:

```
Error |
Error running unit tests: null
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.spockframework.runtime.GlobalExtensionRegistry.startGlobalExtensions(GlobalExtensionRegistry.java:105)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.RunContext.start(RunContext.java:63)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.RunContext.get(RunContext.java:165)
```

Google hasn't been much help. I've done a `clean-all`, deleted the `.grails/2.5.2` folder but just can't track down the root cause.

Comment: Which version of spock is used in the app? You might have to upgrade that to `1.0-groovy-2.3` or `1.0-groovy-2.4` as per the version of Groovy.