# Grails - Upgrading from 2.4.5 to 2.5.5 resulting in Error running unit tests: null

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'm trying to upgrade a Grails app from 2.4.5 to 2.5.5. When I run `test-app`, I'm getting the following:

```
Error running unit tests: null
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
       at org.spockframework.runtime.GlobalExtensionRegistry.startGlobalExtensions(GlobalExtensionRegistry.java:105)
```

Comment: This looks like it may be the same issue as this - upgrading the groovy version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810722/grails-upgrade-2-4-4-to-2-5-2-error-running-unit-tests-null
This shows the groovy version for different Grails versions: https://objectpartners.com/2015/05/14/list-of-groovy-versions-for-each-version-of-grails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clover plugin was the culprit. Upgrading it from version 4.0.2 to version 4.1.2 made the error go away.